# JdbcTemplate.query taking more than 30 min for 10k rows

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a method as below which is taking huge(30 to 35 min) time to get fetch 10k rows.

```
 public List<Map<String,Object>> getMetaData(ITxn txn, String sql){
        List<Map<String,Object>> results= new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        log.debug("Sql ::: "+sql);
        ColumnMapRowMapper rowMapper = new ColumnMapRowMapper();
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(10000);
        results = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
        
        return results;
    }
```

I have also tried queryForList which is taking the same time, but when I run the same query in SQL developer, it gets executed in seconds.

Comment: please show the sql

Comment: did you scroll to line 10000 in sqldeveloper in seconds, too?

Comment: Because you are comparing apples and oranges. Your query in SQL developer is only the execution of the query. In here it will also map each row into an object (which is additional overhead which you don't have with simple SQL developer). Another thing don't use `DriverManagerDataSource` (if you do but aproper datasource) also set the fetch size to something reasonable (default is 10 doing a lot of round trips, try something like 100 or 1000 instead).